# Android get sub String (OTP) from Sms Recived

Tags: java, android

The message body of the received SMS is

> **"Welcome harry gupta,One Time Password to complete registration is VEYA .Please don't share it with anyone."**

I want to extract the substring **"VEYA"** from this message and **"harry gupta"** string different in different messages .

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the secret substring `VEYA` is **always one word** followed **immediately by a fullstop** then the magic code is:

```
secret = message.substring(message.substring(0,message.indexOf(".")).lastIndexOf(" "), message.indexOf("."))
```